# diapo slider doesn't work with jquery larger than 1.7

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I use [Diapo Slider](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/) that work good with jquery 1.7 and lower versions. but to use bootstrap (v3.3.6) I need jquery 1.11 or above.

how can I fix this conflict?

Comment: Which error did you have?

Comment: I don't have error. only when use 1.7 diapo work and some effect from bootstrap (for example Collapse) don't work. when use 1.11 diapo don't work.

Comment: here (http://jextensions.com/camera-jquery-slideshow-joomla/) CameraSlider is used for joomla and author claimed :

    February 28, 2015 – Fixed image path problem and updated module to work with latest jQuery 1.11.1 version.

I test it. but doesn't work for me. maybe solve problem of other persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution for using CameraSlider (At least for me)

in [this forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/camera-slideshow/tFxxW_1d4Wo/2kT2Jc3XWTYJ) give this resolution :

> To use Camera with jQuery 1.10.2 you need to do this:
>   1. Replace "live.(" with "on.(" (There are 4)
>   2. And replace:
>
> if(opts.loader=='pie' && $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9){
>         loader = 'bar';     } else {        loader = opts.loader;   }
>
> with  loader = opts.loader;
>
> Deleting this lines, the application can't check if you're browsing
>   with an old browser. Because this, in line 36, I reccomend to put
>   loader variable in 'bar' because if you put 'pie' some old browsers
>   won't display the slideshow.

I test in jquery 1.11.3 and this solution it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

On the [wordpress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-in-jquery) you can see that others have this problem too.

Also on the [Diapo website](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/) you can see that Diapo slideshow is no more supported.

Instead of Diapo - the [Camera slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/) is suggested, a new free slideshow with an adaptive layout.

Comment: tnx. but camera slideshow have same problem and don't work with 1.11. and from 2012 don't update.

Comment: I have been seen that link in wp forum. but it soesn't solve problem

Comment: Then the solution is to contact component author and require component upgrade.